# $L^1$ convergence on the boundary implies normal convergence inside

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This is a problem Palka. 5.9 Complex analysis of 5.1 section.

$f_n$ is a sequence of functions continuous on closed disk $\overline{\Delta(z_0,r)}=\bar{D}$ and analytic on $D$. Assume $f_n\to \phi$ pointwise convergence and $\phi$ continous and $\int_{\partial D}|f_n-\phi||dz|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Show $f_n$ is normally convergent.

The natural guess is $\phi$'s analytic extension on $D$. So $\exists\tilde{\phi}$ such that $\tilde{\phi}|_{\partial D}=\phi$.

Consider $|\int_{\partial D}\frac{f_n(\eta)-\phi(\eta)}{\eta-z}d\eta|$ and use the estimation above to bound the estimate by small number. However, I do not have control over the denominator as $\eta-z$ can be arbitrarily small. If this is finished, then I have shown uniform convergence which is stronger than normal convergence/locally compact convergence.

Any hint will be sufficient.

Comment: Where is $\phi$ defined?

Comment: @zhw $\phi$ is defined on the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1. Forget about uniform convergence on $\bar D;$ there are counterexamples.

2. If $g$ is continuous on $\partial D$ and $0<s<r,$ then

$$\left |\int_{\partial D}\frac{g(\eta)}{\eta - z}\, d \eta \right | \le \frac{1}{r-s}\cdot \int_{\partial D}|g(\eta)|\, d \eta$$

for all  $z\in \overline {\Delta (z_0,s)}.$